# How does allauth work when user logs in via social registration

Tags: django, registration, django-allauth, user-profile

I have been trying to use [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) to provide Social registration, but I am having trouble configuring the profiles for the user. There is no documentation of django-allauth which tells

1. how a django user account is created when a user logs in via a third party such as facebook
2. What username is assigned to that user and what password is used.
3. Certain third party providers such as Facebook provide a lot of information about the user such as their name, email etc. so how can we get them and save in the user account/profile

If anybody has used allauth in their projects and can provide some details then it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am using django_allauth in my project.

**(1) How a django user account is created when a user logs in via a third party such as facebook ?**

You should take a look at :

1. **your admin panel** and see what happens when somebody logs in.
2. **allauth.facebook.views.login** and try to track the login process

It is something like this (in a few words):

1. When a user logs in your site via his Facebook credentials he is given an access token
2. This token is saved in the FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKENS table (you can see it in the admin panel)
3. With this access token and with the help of Facebook GraphApi we know his social_id
4. When we know his social_id - we can have his Facebook account from our database
5. If we haven't saved it in the db already - we save the Facebook account in the FACEBOOK_ACCOUNTS table (Facebook Accounts in the admin panel)
6. Then we create a user in the USERS table with the data present in the Facebook account. (you can see the new user in the Users section in the admin panel)

**(2) What username is assigned to that user and what password is used ?**

As I mentioned before with the help of Facebook GraphApi we get the username of the Facebook user and it is assigned to the User profile as User.username



**(3) Certain third party providers such as Facebook provide a lot of information about the user such as their name, email etc. so how can we get them and save in the user account/profile?**

Again - the Facebook GraphApi - it gets you the info you need.

I have integrated django_allauth in my site and it is working properly. I will be happy to answer(if I can) if you have more questions.



**EDIT** - For the avatar support...

I think you have to take a look at the [django_allauth settings](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/) and particularly in:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_AVATAR_SUPPORT (= 'avatar' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

> Enable support for django-avatar. When enabled, the profile image of
>   the user is copied locally into django-avatar at signup.

Comment: Although I had eventually figured it out, but still thanks a lot for all the information that you have provided. There is just one thing I don't know how to solve. Currently I gave configured the app such that its get the image from facebook profile, but I realized that this image is not saved, so If the user tries to change the avatar then the image which was brought from social authentication is lost. Is there a way to retain that?

Comment: Thanks for the information, do you know of a way to add support for multiple facebook apps on the same django server?